# Roccat Kave XTD 5.1 Drivers?

Tags: drivers, sound, headset

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to use my new **Roccat Kave XTD 5.1**.

The CD installation doesn't content Linux drivers, and I can't find any drivers in the additional drivers panel of Ubuntu.

Also, I have search on the net and find nothing.

Links that can maybe help you :

http://www.roccat.org/Support/Gaming-Sound/ROCCAT-Kave-XTD/#crb_1

https://launchpad.net/~berfenger/+archive/ubuntu/roccat

Comment: You say you have not found any drives but you have a link to a package called `roccat-tools`. Have you tried to install it?

Answer (score 3):

Roccat Kave XTD doesn't work properly out of the box.

Roccat support team advised to edit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf:

> The Kave XTD 5.1 is officially not designed to be compatible with
>   Linux but we were able to use the Kave XTD under Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
>   (3.5.0-40-generic) without a configuration software, all we had to do
>   was to edit the pulse daemon.conf at /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and add
>   this line:
>
> default-sample-channels = 6
>
> Your system should detect the USB 5.1 soundcard which is built into
>   the KaveXTD just fine. So it *should* work as 5.1 Headset. We were
>   however unable to use neither the pulseaudio-tool nor alsa's
>   speaker-test to test the channels but almighty VLC played the Dolby
>   Test Video
>   (http://www.dolby.com/us/en/consumer/technology/home-theater/dolby-digital-plus-download.html
>   ) just fine with all channels enabled and controllable through the
>   XTD's volume control unit - which should verify that all channels are
>   properly processed by the soundcard.
>
> Please understand that we cannot guarantee you it will work out of the
>   box on your machine with your kernel, you should be prepared to do
>   some trial-and-error config-hacking. You might want to run Kmix to
>   check that no channel is muted by accident.

However it doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 (at least for me). I had distorted sound and subwoofer didn't work at all. 
So I googled a little bit and found working solution not just for Roccat Kave XTD, but for most external usb sound cards:

```
pacmd
list-cards
set-card-profile 1 output:analog-surround-51
```

Comment: This worked for me but make sure that you pick the correct soundcard index in set-card-profile

The one thing that is not yet working is the woofer :/

Comment: legit solution.

Comment: even on 22.04..

Answer (score 0):

roccat-tools is only for mice and keyboards. Your Kave is supported out of the box. Plug it in, configure your desktops sound settings to use this device instead of your internal sound card and you're done.